# What does Mr. Saxon (a.k.a. the Master) tell Martha's mother about the Doctor in series 3, episode 6 "The Lazarus Experiment"?

Tags: doctor-who

What does Mr. Saxon (a.k.a. the Master) tell Martha's mother about the Doctor in series 3, episode 6 "The Lazarus Experiment"?

I have looked all over and the only thing I could find was answers to other questions about the Master but not about what he said.

Comment: I'm new and stupid when I saw this I was so confused like I swear this is different from when I posted it XD

Comment: He told her *"5 billion years from now you're going to be a cat nun nurse and the Doctor is going to let you die"*

Comment: There's nothing useful in the official commentary (*"Hey, what's he saying"? "Yeah, what is he saying?". [Stage whisper] "What's he saying!?!"*)

Comment: There's nothing useful in the actor's commentary. They're still talking about the nudity in the previous scene and skip this one entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Martha's mother Francine did not speak to Harold Saxon personally. In an answerphone message for Martha she said that the information *came* from Harold Saxon, but the message was delivered to her by an unnamed male character at Lazarus' experiment. The 'mystery man' told her:

> "He's dangerous. There are things you should know."

He then whispers further details to her, but we don't hear what they are. Francine finds the Doctor and says that there is "nothing but death and destruction" around him, so evidently this is part of what she was told.

Later, Francine leaves a message on Martha's answerphone saying:

> "Martha, it's your mother. Please phone me back. I'm begging you. I know who this Doctor really is. **I know he's dangerous. You're going to get yourself killed.** Please, trust me. This information comes from Harold Saxon himself. You're not safe!"

In previous stories (for example, the TV Movie) The Master has claimed that *he* is the benevolent Timelord and The Doctor is the evil one - effectively reversing their roles. It is possible that Francine was told something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

We can guess that Harold Saxon whispered something along the lines of “All The Doctor brings is death and destruction everywhere he goes.” We can guess that Saxon whispered this into Martha’s mothers ear because shortly after, Martha’s mom says “he is dangerous, I’ve been told things,” and even later she says, to Martha, “Look around you. Nothing but death and destruction.”

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to be very similar to the existing answer; do you have any evidence to support this?